# gSOAP dynamic array as input parameter

Tags: c++, web-services, gsoap

I generate soap service and client using gSOAP toolkit which is supposed to send an int array which is put in a struct as is suggested in gSOAP docs:

//myservice.h

```
struct abc {
    int __size;
    int *__myptr;
};

int ns__SetConfiguration(struct abc as, int* result);
```

Here is how I generate codes:

```
soapcpp2 -i -SC myservice.h
```

Then from the client I call the service:

```
int result;
int *aa = (int*)soap_malloc(&service, 10*sizeof(int));
abc myabc;

myabc.__myptr = aa;
myabc.__size = 10;

service.setConfiguration(myabc, &result);
```

However, on the service side, **size** becomes **ZERO**.
What am I missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mistyped.

Struct exactly should be defined like this:

```
struct abc {
int *__ptr;
int __size;
```

};